# Metal Frame Capture wrong geometry

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, metal, metalkit

Can you explain me what I'm doing wrong.

When I capture frame of my simple renderer and if double click `geometry` it shows me wrong things.

[image]

video here - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JuoiDdGh-HFmpiYqvSld3O2RFVmrWnMA/view?usp=sharing

How can I fix this?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "shows me wrong things"?

Comment: I drawn 3d tree, but geometry tool shows strange lines.

Comment: Please provide additional screenshots.

Comment: I've added video record

Comment: Video won't work.

Comment: You need to show your code.